# Nlog does not create Root element in xml file document while writting logs for different log level in same file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-5, nlog

Nlog writes log successfully for different log levels, but is does not create Root element in same file for different log levels. Due to this Invalid Xml Format issues is encountered. I think i have missed something in Nlog.Config or somewhere. Please help me with this.

This is the output which i am getting for different log levels without Root Element:

```
  <logevent time="2019-08-07 10:44:08.7467" level="DEBUG"> 
     <Message>System.Exception: test debug</Message><Exception>test 
     debug</Exception>
   </logevent>
   <logevent time="2019-08-07 10:44:08.8426" level="WARN"> 
      <Message>Serious 
       error</Message><Exception>Object reference not set to an instance 
       of an object.</Exception>
    </logevent>
    <logevent time="2019-08-07 10:45:19.6269" level="WARN"> 
       <Message>Serious error</Message><Exception>Object reference not 
       set to an instance of an object.</Exception>
     </logevent>


  <target name="xmlFile" xsi:type="File" 
      fileName="${basedir}\log\Xmartlog.${shortdate}.xml" 
       archiveFileName="${basedir}\log\log.${shortdate}.xml"
        maxArchiveFiles="4"
        archiveAboveSize="10240"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        encoding="utf-8"  >
    <layout xsi:type="XmlLayout" includeAllProperties="false">
      <attribute  name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
      <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
      <element name="Message" 
       value="${message:exceptionSeparator=String}"/>
       <element name="Exception" value="${exception:format=message}" />
     </layout>
  </target> 

 There should be output like this:
  <Log>
    ----logs should be here----
   </Log>
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3537

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not clear documented, but this is correct.

When writing to a file, it will be appended. Constantly removing the end-root-element (or insert content instead if append) , would be difficult with performance and multithreading.

I would recommend to add the root element as first step before processing the file.

Comment: how to add the root element as first step before processing the file. is this can be done at nlog.config or at code level ?

Comment: You need some code for that. (.Net, Powershell, etc). It's not built into NLog unfortunately.

Comment: solved problem by adding adding header and footer attributes in target tag     
    <target name="xmlFile" xsi:type="File" 
     fileName="${basedir}\log\Xmartlog.${shortdate}.xml" 
     archiveFileName="${basedir}\log\log.${shortdate}.xml" keepFileOpen="false" 
    archiveAboveSize="1240" archiveNumbering="Sequence" header="&lt;?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='XmartLogViewer.xsl'?&gt; &lt;nlog&gt;" 
     footer="&lt;/nlog&gt;" concurrentWrites="true" createDirs="true" autoFlush="true" encoding="utf-8"  >

Comment: @NepoKale Remember to add `archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"` in case you restart your application.

Comment: I wrote a powershell script to add end tag of root element 
https://github.com/solo-developer/NLog.TagEnder